# A design pattern that mimics a Flowchart?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, node.js

I am designing a process of transforming a JSON object to HTML/CSS. It consists of:

- Identifying special components
- Extracting the special components
- Parsing the styles
- Parsing the layout etc...

I am currently working with a promise chain:

```
Promise.resolve(true)
    .then(copyBluePrint)
    .then(transformJsx)
    .then(readInputHTML)
    .then(writeOutputHTML)
    .then(uploadToHosting)
    .then(generateLink)
    .then(updateBuildRequest)
    .then(finish)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('err -> ', err, err.stack);
    });
```

I have two main problems:

1. **Strict workflow:** a stage cannot change the course of the process if needed.
2. **No payload:** I have no main payload that is passed between the stages.

I am looking for a pattern, preferable that can be implemented on NodeJS, that acts as a Flowchart - i.e a payload is passed & the flow across the stages is dynamic. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say dynamic... How dynamic does it need to be?  Does the flow need the ability to change *itself* at runtime, or do you merely need a more flexible way to define workflows without writing new code and recompiling?  Normally there is some controller somewhere that actually executes the flows... is it your intention to define the flow within the actual payload, rather than externally to the workflow?

Comment: Dynamic such as if an inner process decides it can add more links to the chain or remove links. If an external controller is the best way to go about it, the payload should consist of an optional flowChanges that are returned from each link.

Comment: I see.  Where I work, we use a workflow system that the CTO designed that is driven from SQL Server tables.  In theory, any stage could potentially rewire itself by simply running a SQL query.  In practice, I can't imagine that ever happening, since stages can be executed conditionally and re-routes can occur based on a boolean value returned from the stage.

Comment: Because the engine is SQL-based, the payload can be anything that is storable in a table.  Actually, we also have a document repository (a networked file folder), so the payload can literally be anything.  The Task Record (a container that passes between stages) has its own XML payload.  So hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: If you're not averse to JNI, you should also look at Akka.  That said, all of these things are a bit larger than the scale you're working at.

Comment: It is an interesting approach. I like the fact that using an external state for the process gives you a single point of truth and the benefit of logging.

Comment: What about the builder pattern, it should give you the dynamic you need and it would be stateless.

Comment: What does this have to do with UML??

Comment: @RubberDuck You are right. It doesn't :-). Flowchart was the term I was aiming for. I will now make the appropriate changes. Tnx.

Comment: @Guy: I highly recommend to inform yourself about [Flow Design](http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2011/03/19/flow-design-cheat-sheet-ndash-part-i-notation.aspx), and its proposed [implementation](http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2011/03/19/flow-design-cheat-sheet-ndash-part-i-notation.aspx). Westphal has also written a complete book "Messaging as a Programming Model " about this. Of course, not specificially for Javascript/Node.js, but I guess you will be able to translate it.

Comment: ... so what you are asking for requires more than just "a design pattern". You are asking for a complete programming model.

Answer (score 2):

From the look of the example you provided, what you may need is simply to reify function composition;

E.g.,

```
function transform1(input) {
    ...
    return output;
}

function transform2(input) {
    ...
    return output;
}
```

Then, you could define, when the need for a "transform3 < = > first transform1, then transform2" arises, as,

```
 function compose(from, to) {
    return function(input) {
        return to(from(input));
    }
 }

 transform3 = compose(transform1, transform2)
```

You are then still free to store and manage your first-class transform functions however you like, as well as encode in their input and output some common data to signal whether the chain of composition ought to continue applying compose() or not.

'Hope this helps.